# Show default and error image while loading image from blob

Tags: html, css, image

I am making a image gallery in my project using html css. In it I am displaying images from blob and I want to show a default image so that if due to any reason my image do not load user will see the default thumbnails and same in the case of image not available on blob.

I tried:

```
<div>                    
    <img src="@Model.ComponentData.imagePath" onclick="OpenBookRead(@Model.ComponentData.Id)" class="actualImage"/>
    <img src="@Model.ComponentData.imagePath" onclick="OpenBookRead(@Model.ComponentData.Id)" class="defaultImage"/>
</div>


<style>
    .actualImage{
        position:absolute;
        height:150px;
        width:100px;
    }
    .defaultImage{
        height:150px;
        width:100px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I have added 1 answer. Please check.

Comment: Please check updated answer

Answer (score 3):

Please try with below code

Your HTML

```
<div>                    
    <img src="@Model.ComponentData.imagePath" onclick="OpenBookRead(@Model.ComponentData.Id)" class="actualImage"/>
    <img src="@Model.ComponentData.imagePath" onclick="OpenBookRead(@Model.ComponentData.Id)" class="defaultImage"/>
</div>
```

Please add css property "opacity" to your style

```
<style>
   .actualImage {
      opacity: 0;
      position:absolute;
      height:150px;
      width:100px;        
   }
   .actualImage.show-actual-image {
      opacity: 1;
   }
  .defaultImage {
     height:150px;
     width:100px;
   }
</style>
```

Add following script to manage opacity based on your actual image availability

```
<script>
    $(".actualImage")
   .on('load', function() { $(this).addClass("show-actual-image");})
   .on('error', function() { $(this).removeClass("show-actual- image");});
</script>
```

I think this will help you....

You can use following code also...
It works fine

HTML

```
<div class="Landscape" style="position: relative;">
   <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ_Tm3R3OxcWhSFwaLNhG0iQUq2RqT3pnTEgSN3u1YDc44lMRWlFA" class="actualImage" />
   <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTCb5jUiDyPAQM2DmOn9V37FJwHUkaeCTTIsorbI-tKegIDHb-qZQ" class="defaultImage" />
```

## CSS

```
.landscape {
  position: relative;
  height: 130px;
  width: 198px;
}
.actualImage,
.defaultImage{
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   z-index: 1;
 }
.actualImage {
   opacity: 0;
}
.actualImage.show-actual-image {
   opacity: 1;
   z-index: 999;
}
```

## Javascript

```
var imgElement = document.getElementsByClassName("actualImage")[0];
if (imgElement.complete) { 
  alert("hi");
  imgElement.className += " show-actual-image";     
}
```

Comment: I tried it but it is showing my default image only.

Comment: Check whether show-actual-image class is added. If it is added then give a style   "z-index: 1"

Comment: I tried by putting alert in on load but event  is not triggering.

Comment: Let me check. I will reply soon.

Comment: Please try with this if codition instead of that event.... It is worked for me...          if (document.getElementsByClassName("actualImage")[0].complete) { $(".actualImage").addClass("show-actual-image");} else { $(".actualImage").removeClass("show-actual-image");}

Comment: still i cant see actual image

Comment: Sorry, I have updated your code. This works fine https://jsfiddle.net/4d4du2jm/5/

Comment: You didn't add jQuery to this. That was your problem. So now I have written using javascript only

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140046/discussion-between-surya-raj-m-and-sonali).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `object` tag to put your image source link. Afterwards place an `img` tag inside that object (this img will act as a thumbmail if the source image in the object does not load)

Here is a snippet where the object tag has a valid image source

```css
object,object *{
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
}
```

```html
<object data="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTCb5jUiDyPAQM2DmOn9V37FJwHUkaeCTTIsorbI-tKegIDHb-qZQ" >
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ_Tm3R3OxcWhSFwaLNhG0iQUq2RqT3pnTEgSN3u1YDc44lMRWlFA"/>
</object>
```

Below is another snippet where the object tag has an invalid image source (it will fall back to the `img` thumbail)

```css
object,object *{
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
}
```

```html
<object data=""  onclick="alert()">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ_Tm3R3OxcWhSFwaLNhG0iQUq2RqT3pnTEgSN3u1YDc44lMRWlFA"/>
</object>
```

Comment: does object tags supports cross browser?

Comment: but when the image is taking time to load there is no default thumbnail behind it, it is working only when there is error in loading image